# Android - Unable to reference values from library module

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android application I have set one module to depend on another module (library module), but I am unable to access the values from the library module. For example lets say I want to use `@string/app_desc` from the library, in the AndroidManifest, it will not let me.

How do I fix this?

Comment: how do you include the library into your project?

Comment: I added `compile project(":moduleName")` to the gradle dependencies {}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the package name to it, for example, if you want to reference android own's resources, you do `@android:....`, so to reference resources from another package, you have to use that package name in place of 'android' in the `@android:string/some_string`, so it would be `@your_package_name:string/app_desc`

Comment: does this mean `@com.myname.package:string/app_desc`?

Comment: Whatever the package name is